# How to execute an ActionList item from a TListViewItem

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tlistview, tactionlist

I'm trying to execute an action (TakePhotoFromCameraAction) in a TActionList, when a TListViewItem is selected.

Neither TlistView nor TListViewItem have an Action property, so I've tried calling ActionList[0].Execute in the event, but nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Further:
The code is very simple, as it was just a test for this problem. I was focussing on the ActionList as that was what I will use (when I sort it out).
Button1 doesn't work (it always fails, even when button 2 doesn't), whereas the (new) Button2 does work OK.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ActionList1: TActionList;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    TakePhotoFromCameraAction1: TTakePhotoFromCameraAction;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     ActionList1[0].Execute;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     if TakePhotoFromCameraAction1.Execute
     then
         Memo1.Lines.add('Photo OK')
     else
         Memo1.Lines.add('Photo Fail');
end;
```

Comment: Since we know that `Execute` works, clearly there is a defect in your code. Please produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can use good old `tag` property of TListViewItem to store pointer to TAction you want to use with this item. Of course, you can't set it in object inspector, but can do it programmaticaly in TForm.onCreate event or some other convenient place. It has type NativeInt which has the same size as pointer be it 32-bit or 64-bit architecture, so it should work properly.

Something like this:

```
//in formCreate or other place to initialize actions:
TakePhotoItem.Tag:=NativeInt(TakePhotoFromCameraAction);
SavePhotoItem.Tag:=NativeInt(SavePhotoAction);
//...

//onitemchange event handler
if AItem.Tag<>0 then
  TAction(AItem.Tag).Execute;
```

Maybe it's better to introduce your own descendant of TListViewItem which has Action property, that way you'll have to populate your listview in code only, adding not basic TListViewItem, but TActionListViewItem (name of your class), that has more work to do but will yield more understandable code.

Comment: Lots of different ways to obtain an action, but if asker can't get Execute to do anything, why would a different route to obtain the action change things?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan To me it seems that OP would like to use many times tested method to initiate action just assigning Action property, didn't find it, tried to do it otherwise and now when nothing works, blames actionList[0].Execute, though this line should work (bad habit to call action with predefined index but whatever). You're right, OP should check is action.Execute really called and why action does nothing.

Comment: I agree entirely that `ActionList[0]` is no good. But I think that the asker needs to be steered towards asking a real question. Since we know that `Execute` works, we have to ask what is actually the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments. I guess that the fundamental question is the best way to execute an action in code, rather than as a property.

Comment: The answer seems to be not to focus on the list, rather to focus on the Action.    So to execute an action manually is simply a matter of, in this case:    TakePhotoFromCameraAction1.Execute;    I sill don't see why accessing the list directly doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @SteveGraham set breakpoints to see is TakePhotoFromCameraAction1.Execute really called, what happens in this method that you don't get what you want. Maybe you rely on Update procedure to set some variables, but this Update is never called because there is no visual control depending on action properties (enabled etc).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference (except being ugly) to call `ActionList1[0].Execute;` versus `Action1.Execute;`.

You didn't show the the `.fmx` file so I can't know what linkage you may have setup between the components, but, **it seems you haven't assigned anything to the actions OnExecute event**, and therefore do not get the expected response to the `Execute` call.

The FMX Version of the documentation is not very clear, but the VCL version is (IMO) better (In a brief test I don't see any difference in actual functionality):
From [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.ActnList.TCustomAction.Execute) :

> Responds when a client control "fires".
>
> Execute is called automatically when a client control "fires" (for
>   example, when the user clicks a button or selects a menu item). It
>   returns True if an event handler is found to handle the action, False
>   if there was no event handler or if the action was not enabled.

but you can ofcourse also call `Execute` directly as you tried. And further

> Execute first ensures that the action is updated. Then, if the Enabled
>   property is True, it attempts to handle the action by generating an
>   OnExecute event on the action list that contains this action (if the
>   action belongs to an action list). If the action list's OnExecute
>   event handler does not handle the action, Execute generates an
>   OnActionExecute event on the application itself. If neither the action
>   list nor the application handles the action in response to these
>   events, Execute generates an OnExecute event on itself. If this action
>   has no OnExecute event handler, Execute instructs the application to
>   locate the current target control and call the ExecuteTarget method,
>   which is the mechanism by which predefined action classes perform
>   their function.

Note that you can handle the actions in `TActionList.OnExecute` or in the `TAction.OnExecute`

Comment: OK, the problem is solved. I've had to do a reinstall of Windows 7 and Delphi on the VM, reinstalling everything, and the problem has gone away. Some other things were a bit odd - e.g. I couldn't log into Slack.